# Invoking SNS from cross account using API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am having an API gateway end point in my AWS account which will invoke a SNS in another AWS account in same region.

The access policy in API gateway in my account is like follows

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:604970532282:PublishSourceMsgTopic"
    }
]
}
```

The sns arn : arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:604970532282:PublishSourceMsgTopic belongs to another AWS account in same region.

The json of the access policy configured in the above SNS is :

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "__default_policy_ID",
"Statement": [
 {
  "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
  },
  "Action": [
    "SNS:Publish",
    "SNS:RemovePermission",
    "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
    "SNS:DeleteTopic",
    "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
    "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
    "SNS:Receive",
    "SNS:AddPermission",
    "SNS:Subscribe"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:604970532282:PublishSourceMsgTopic",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "AWS:SourceOwner": "604970532282"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "__console_pub_0",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::148445556582:root"
  },
  "Action": "SNS:Publish",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:604970532282:PublishSourceMsgTopic"
}
]
 }
```

When I am invoking the API Gateway its showing the following error :

```
User: arn:aws:sts::148445556582:assumed-role/api_gateway_sns_role/BackplaneAssumeRoleSession is not 
authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast- 
1:604970532282:PublishSourceMsgTopic
```

I am able to invoke the SNS successfully if i am giving SNS topic which is configured in my AWS account.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving permission for the root owner of the external account to publish on the topic, but the actual publish request is using the role of the API gateway.

So in your access policy, you'll need to give the publish permission to the role the API Gateway is using, not the role of root.

Typically what you would do is set "Principal": "*" and then add conditions under resource in the policy to match the account and arn of the resource accessing SNS from another account.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "SNS:Publish",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:444455556666:MyTopic",
    "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {
        "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-2:111122223333:alarm:MyAlarm"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

There are several example access policies [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-grant-aws-account-access-to-topic), that should help you.

Comment: Thanks K Mo...I will try your suggestion and confirm.Meanwhile can you confirm if I give the Principal as Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      } ,will this work?

Comment: Theoretically, although I've never tried it. "Principal": "*" would definately work. I've added a link to my answer with several example policies that you should be able to adapt.

Comment: I tried with two approach 1.Giving the API Gateway role in Principal i.e :  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/api_gateway_sns_role"
  } 2.Principal": { "AWS": "*" } and adding the conditions,but no luck.Do i need to provide any access policy in Api Gateway

Comment: Try "Principal": "*".  I've updated my answer to give a fuller example. Just relace the arns with your SNS resource and the api gateway resource from the other account.

Comment: Tried that but no luck..my rough guess is there might be some issues with API Gateway..I tried the same with S3...i.e I gave the resource arn of S3 and that worked.